# Minimizing expected value of absolute difference

Tags: optimization, expected-value

U is a random variable that follows Uniform distribution with interval (0,1).
X1, ..., Xn follows Bernoulli distribution with mean U.
How do I find the function *f*:(0,1)^{n} -> R that minimizes
E[(U-*f*(X1, ..., Xn))^2)] ?
I have no idea where to start solving.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it Bernoulli distribution with mean E[U]?

Comment: No, just random variable U that follows uniform distribution

Comment: And should it be $E[(U - f)^2]$ instead of $E[U - f^2]$?

Comment: That was my mistake. Sorry for confusion. Fixed it!

Comment: Is there any other information on the $X_i$ and/or can you link the original question?

Answer (score 0):

The $X_i$ follow a Bernoulli distribution with mean $U$. This means that the success probability of each $X_i$ is $U$. Additionally we know that $0 \leq E[(U - f)^2] = E[U^2] - 2E[Uf] + E[f^2]$.

First we find E[U^2]. The moment generating function for $U$ is $M_U(t) = E[e^{tU}] = \int_0^1 e^{tu}du = \frac{1}{t}e^{tu}\vert_0^1 = \frac{e^t - 1}{t}$. Then $$E[U^2] = \left(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}M_U(t)\right)\Big\vert_{t=0} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{e^t(t^2 - 2t +2) - 2}{t^3} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e^t(t^2 - 2t +2) + e^t(2t-2)}{3t^2} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e^t}{3} = \frac{1}{3}.$$

We could've also done this by finding the pdf of $U^2$. This would be done  by noticing that $F_{U^2}(u) = \mathbb{P}(U^2 \leq u) = \mathbb{P}(0 \leq U \leq \sqrt{u}) = \sqrt{u}$ so $f_{U^2}(u) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}$ and then taking the expectation as usual.

I'm not certain about the rest yet...